What is the fastest algorithm in SIMD to compare a pattern with a bit mask?
I want to optimize the following code in SIMD

pat:    [1, 2, 3, 4]
data:   [1, 1, 3, 3]
mask:   [1, 0, 1, 1] # 1 indicates equal, 0 indicates optional/don't care
result: [1, 1, 1, 0]

naive algorithm for result:
  for i in range(len(pat)):
    result[i] = mask[i] ? pat[i] == data[i] : 1

alternative naive algorithm for result:
  for i in range(len(pat)):
    result[i] = !mask[i] || pat[i] == data[i]

Here's what I did with Rust portable SIMD:
fn simd_match<const N: usize>(pattern: [u8; N], mask: u64, data: [u8; N]) -> Mask<i8, N>
where
    LaneCount<N>: SupportedLaneCount,
{
    Mask::from_bitmask(mask)
        .select_mask(
            Simd::from_array(data).simd_eq(Simd::from_array(pattern)),
            Mask::from_bitmask(u64::MAX),
        )
}

Is there any way to improve this? I would like to know the best way to do it under different CPU situation, e.g. if AVX512BW is available then vpcmpb/kmovd can be used.
I tried implementing it in Rust with multiversioning function that does runtime detection, but I'm not sure if my target selection is enough:
#[inline(always)]
#[multiversion(targets(
    "x86_64+avx512bw",
    "x86_64+avx2",
    "x86_64+avx",
    "x86_64+sse4.2",
    "x86_64+sse2",
    "x86+avx512bw",
    "x86+avx2",
    "x86+avx",
    "x86+sse4.2",
    "x86+sse2",
    "aarch64+sve2",
    "aarch64+sve",
    "aarch64+neon",
    "arm+neon",
    "arm+vfp4",
    "arm+vfp3",
    "arm+vfp2",
    
))]

fn simd_match<const N: usize>(pattern: [u8; N], mask: u64, data: [u8; N]) -> bool
where
    LaneCount<N>: SupportedLaneCount,
{
    Mask::from_bitmask(mask)
        .select_mask(
            Simd::from_array(data).simd_eq(Simd::from_array(pattern)),
            Mask::from_bitmask(u64::MAX),
        )
        .all()
}


Your use of conditionals and boolean expressions with short-circuit semantics prevents the compiler from loading data[i] and pat[i] if the mask is 0. That hinders vectorization. Change it to bitwise logic and the compiler should be able to vectorize itself. result[i] = (mask[i] == 0) | (pat[i] == data[i])

AArch64 without SVE is somewhat non-obvious, and the best choice might depend on what you want to do with the result.  e.g. it's efficient to compare and narrow bytes to nibbles with shrn to get a mask with 4 bits per element, so if your bitmaps are small, storing them unpacked to nibbles or even bytes would make these operations more efficient.  But if they (and the data) don't fit in L1d cache, it can be worth spending more cycles to work with 1-bit mask elements.

I see your masks are only a single u64, so holding mask data in a SIMD vector might not be prohibitive...  But bitscan for stuff like lowest-set is more efficient with scalar masks.

In case it's not obvious, the asm you want for x86 without AVX-512 is [v]pcmpeqb / [v]pmovmskb to get a scalar mask, then scalar integer and (perhaps after combining two to four 16-bit masks into a 32-bit or 64-bit register with shift/OR)  With AVX-512 zero-masked compare-into-mask is probably your best bet, like vpcmpeqb k1{k1}, ymm0, [rdi]  (the normal z suffix on the {} is implicit; compares only support zero-masking)  _mm256_mask_cmp_epi8_mask or _mm512_...

Depending on use-case, AVX2 compare / movemask might be better than going through k registers even if AVX-512BW is available.  Especially for sizes <= 32 elements so it's still only one vector without using ZMM.

The asm you want for x86 without AVX-512 is [v]pcmpeqb / [v]pmovmskb to get a scalar mask, then scalar integer and (perhaps after combining two to four 16-bit masks into a 32-bit or 64-bit register with shift/OR).
Your intrinsics look like they're turning the u64 mask into a vector, which is significantly less convenient especially if you ultimately want or can use a bitmask rather than a vector.  (is there an inverse instruction to the movemask instruction in intel avx2? - no, you have to emulate it with a few instructions).
With AVX-512 zero-masked compare-into-mask is an option which does the AND for free, like vpcmpeqb k1{k1}, zmm0, [rdi] (the normal z suffix on the {} is implicit; compares only support zero-masking not merge-masking, but the asm syntax unfortunately requires omitting the z).  Intrinsics _mm512_mask_cmp_epi8_mask, or _mm256_...  or 128 if you want to use this with narrower vectors.
The masking will suppress faults from the load of the memory source operand; with intrinsics you might need to use a masked load with the same mask as the compare, but hopefully plain _mm512_loadu_si512 can still fold into a memory source operand for a masked compare since out-of-bounds access is UB, faulting isn't a required side effect.
But for 32-byte or smaller vectors, AVX2 compare/movemask is probably still optimal for many use-cases even when AVX-512 is available.  Intel CPUs only run vpcmpb on port 5, competing with kmov k, mem/reg.  kmov reg, k runs on port 0, same as kand.  kmov mem, k is a pure store, no ALU unlike loads. (https://uops.info/)
If you only need this rarely as part of a larger program that doesn't use 512-bit vectors, you might want to avoid them here, too.  AVX-512 kunpckdq can concatenate two 32-bit masks in one instruction, but it only runs on port 5 on Intel, and you'd still have to get the mask data into and maybe back out of k registers.

AArch64 without SVE is somewhat non-obvious, and the best choice might depend on what you want to do with the result. e.g. it's efficient to compare and narrow bytes to nibbles with shrn to get a mask with 4 bits per element.  (This is the usual starting point for finding a match position within a 16-byte vector, e.g. as part of a strlen or memchr: compare / shrn by 4 and fmov that to a 64-bit integer reg for clz or rbit/clz).
So if your bitmaps are small, storing them unpacked to nibbles (4 mask bits per element) or even bytes (8 bits per element) would make these operations more efficient. But if they (and the data) don't fit in L1d cache, it can be worth spending more cycles to unpack / repack down to 1-bit mask elements.
I see your masks are only a single u64, so holding mask data in a SIMD vector might not be prohibitive... But bitscan for stuff like lowest-set is more efficient with scalar masks.  If you just need to test for any non-zero, you can OR together some masks and compare against zero, then shrn/fmov and tst that integer mask to see if any of the mask elements were non-zero.
